# Retag questions with [haskell] and [stack] to [haskell-stack] if they pertain to the Haskell stack tool

Tags: discussion, retag-request

[Most questions that carry the [haskell] and [stack] tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/haskell+stack?sort=newest) should be tagged with [haskell-stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/haskell-stack) instead of [stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stack).

I would appreciate if someone could help me complete these edits.

Comment: Mmm....? What's stopping you from doing it?

Comment: I have less than 2000 points, so my suggested edits are rate-limited.

Comment: Well, do one at a time, and I'm sure you will get them all in no time.

Comment: @Braiam Thanks for the encouragement! :)

Comment: Especially since you don't have full edit privileges, when you're doing the retagging, **make sure to fix other obvious problems with the post, too!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I'm done for now. I've set up a website monitoring tool to notify me of new questions with the two tags.