# Automatically suggest tag combinations

Tags: feature-request, tags

I repeatedly experience questions with multiple tags that would be better off being merged into a single, different tag. I've had this "problem" myself when asking before, and only ever noticed it after reviewing my tags before posting.

Suppose the following tags:

> Tags: [user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/user)[interaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/interaction)

Obviously, the poster would be better off using the [user-interaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/user-interaction) tag, but since `user` and `interaction` are two different words, often times a user will just write down the words that come to his mind, in that order, without checking whether a better tag exists.

Quite recently, the [user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/user)-tag has been [burninated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268187/the-user-tag-has-been-burninated). This issue might have been what sparked interest in the [user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/user)-tag in the first place. A great relevant example would be the tags [api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/api) and [design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/design), which are mistakenly being used for the [api-design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/api-design)-tag.

**So, I'd like to propose an improvement for this:** Whenever a user types two tags after each other, and there is a slash-combined version for those tags, show a little box to notify the user. He may then choose to use the combined tag, or dismiss if the suggestion was wrong.

[image]

This could prevent a lot of wrong tagging and also lower the amount of tags that are heavily used but serve no real meaning (*cough, [user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/user)).

Please let me know what you think of this idea.

Comment: It's understandable for a new user to find 2 tags that express what they want, not understanding or being aware that one tag consisting of both words would be more appropriate.  Good [̶f̶e̶a̶t̶u̶r̶e̶]̶ ̶[̶r̶e̶q̶u̶e̶s̶t̶]̶  [feature-request].

Comment: This sounds like a good idea, but there might be edge cases worth considering. As a (not very concerning) example, [tag:haskell] plus [tag:stack] are often [misused](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/340785/2751851) when the OP actually means [tag:haskell-stack], and this suggestion would help with that; however, there are a few questions which are correctly tagged as [haskell][stack].

Comment: This is a non trivial feature, and while it may be nice to have, it is not exactly need to have.

Comment: Your 3 examples involve 6 tags which should not exist, so that doesn't really motivate it well IMO (because we should get rid of those tags, not spend time making things work better while they exist). A better example might be [binary] [tree], although I'm not sure how many of these combinations there really are (I've seen plenty of [x] [api] questions that should be [x-api], and there's also [binary] [search], but that's again involving tags that shouldn't exist).